# List view on subsites with filtered choice field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, column, filter, sub-site

I have a site with a list of projects. I then have multiple subsites which represents all the companies.

I need to have a page on each subsite that contains the projects list with a specific view.

I also need to be able to filter a column of the list depanding on another column. Lets say i have a column named Country and one named City.I need the city column to show values depanding on what Country was chosen, this is in the form where you create or modify and item.

Sharepoint 2010.

Comment: So, you need to create cascade fields on the New/Edit form, where second field will load its values depending on first field's value, right? What type are you going to use for that fields (choice/taxonomy)?

Comment: Yes thats it. It would be choice and then lookup list i guess ? I just have no idea how to properly do it, anything that works goes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good and simple way to implement cascading dropdowns is to use [SPServices jquery library SPCascadeDropdowns function](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation).